# How to add images from a resource folder to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, bitmap

Okay so I have created a `dictionary` that holds a string and a corresponding `bitmap` image. I have added all the relevant images into the projects resources properly and have tried a few different approaches to adding them into a `dictionary` on run time to make it easier to access the images depending on what letter is input. This is my code for creating the `dictionary` and my attempt to populate it from my resources.

```
Dictionary<String,Image> namesAndImages = new Dictionary<String, Image>();

var resources = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry myResource in resources)
{
    if (myResource.Value is Bitmap) //is this resource is associated with an image
    {
        String resName = myResource.Key.ToString(); //get resource's name
        Image resImage = myResource.Value as Image; //get the Image itself

        namesAndImages.Add(resName, resImage);
    }
}
```

For whatever reason it doesn't seem to add any of the images to the dictionary. I have tested a few different key value pairs and theres nothing in it at all. Any ideas folks?

Comment: Using VS2017 I can just add a resource file named `Resource1` and add an image named `Image1`, then access it as `Resource1.Image1`, which is a `Bitmap`. Is this option not available to you?

Comment: Im using VS2012 and its just 'Resource' but ive nearly 40 images and it takes a considerable amount of time to load them individually due to their size which is why i want to have it done automatically using a 'foreach' loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<Resource file name>.ResourceManager` the get the `ResourceManager` associated with the given resource file. The images can be accessed like so:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> dict = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
var resourceManager = Resource1.ResourceManager;
var resources = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in resources)
{
    if (item.Value is Bitmap)
    {
        dict.Add(item.Key as string, item.Value as Image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tamás I will have a look now and see if this fixes the problem and let you know. Cheers

Comment: That was perfect Tamás. It now seems to be populating the dictionary with the appropriate images and text. Much appreciated.